# Using Anchor Link in wp_link_pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, anchor

I want users to be able to press 'Next Page' button in a single post to continue to the next page in the same post, pointing to a specific anchor, let's say #content.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364914/wordpress-how-to-add-anchor-to-previous-next-page-links) but it is for navigating between posts, I want to apply this on a specific post with more than 1 page.

Using [[wp_link_pages]](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages)

```
<?php
    $defaults = array(
        'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
        'after'            => '</p>',
        'link_before'      => '',
        'link_after'       => '',
        'next_or_number'   => 'number',
        'separator'        => ' ',
        'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
        'pagelink'         => '%',
        'echo'             => 1
    );

        wp_link_pages( $defaults );

?>
```

These are the arguments I have.

Any help would be much appreciated. Have a nice day!

Comment: I think that you can do `'pagelink'         => '%#content',`. Can you give that a shot?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work    pagelink 
(string) Format string for page numbers.  % in the string will be replaced with the number, so Page % would generate "Page 1", "Page 2", etc. Defaults to %.